# Como exibir dados (.log) , em tempo real, em uma pagina HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Então, estou tentando fazer um logger que possa ser visualizado em uma pagina HTML, em tempo real. A pagina carrega todos os arquivos .log's (de: /clearing-dit/logs/) e possibilita clicar em cada um para mostrar seu conteúdo.

```
<button type="submit" class="list-group-item link">
   <i class="fa fa-fw fa-history"></i> [[${l.filename}]]
   <span class="badge" th:text="${#dates.format(l.lastModified,'dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')}">10/09/1992 23:55:23</span>
   <span class="badge" th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(l.size, 1, 3)}+MB">10MB</span>
 </button>
```

Uma vez selecionado o arquivo, é pego as ultimas 50 linhas do .log ( que é como se fosse um .txt)

```
 public void fileNumberLines(Log log) throws IOException {

 InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
    try {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChar = 0;
        while ((readChar = inputStream.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < readChar; ++i) {
                if (byteArray[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        log.setFinalLine(count);
        log.setInitLine(count - 50 > 0 ? count - 50 : 0);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

E retornado o conteúdo dessas 50:

```
    private String getLogContentByRange(int lineOccurrence, int firstLine, int lastLine, String logPath) {
        BufferedReader buffRead;
        int lineNumber = 1;
        String content = "";
        File file = new File(logPath);

        try {
            buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;
            do {
                line = "";
                line = buffRead.readLine();
                if (lineNumber <= lastLine && lineNumber >= firstLine) {
                    if (lineNumber == lineOccurrence) {
                        content += "<mark style='background-color: red; color: white;'>" + lineNumber + ". " + line + "</mark>\n";
                    } else {
                        content += lineNumber + ". " + line + "\n";
                    }
                }
                lineNumber++;
            } while (line != null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Esse log é retornado e acessado no HTML:

```
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <pre>
                        <p th:utext="${log.content}">Log content</p>
                    </pre>
                </div>
```

**O meu problema é:** Como eu faço para continuar "printando" as informações de um arquivo, conforme ele vai sendo incrementado/editado? Existe algum jeito de deixar a verificação "ociosa", a espera de novas atualizações? Queria fazer como se os dados estivessem sendo vistos em um console, onde é possível dar o comando grep e derivados.

Comment: Java não é minha especialidade, mas sei que tem uma classe chamada `WatchService` que permite "monitorar" uma pasta por alterações, o que dispara um evento e você pode ler novamente o log quando ele for alterado. Aqui um exemplo do SO em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251508/4730201

Answer (score 1):

Fala Davi! Você pode fazer uma chamada javascript que "estarta" de x em x segundos! O problema é que a latência para se abrir um arquivo txt, percorrer as linhas e fechar esse arquivo e, por fim, renderizar o conteúdo na tela é bem alto! Por isso, seria legal você colocar um processo em ajax para chamar um método na camada de controle (JSF, Struts ou Spring MVC) de 10 em 10 segundos.

Veja esse exemplo em Primefaces: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml